# PrintScreen em C#

Tags: c#

Quero fazer um programa que tire printscreen de uma janela definida por mim em C#
Até agora fiz esse código:

```
        private void btPrintScreenEcra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Definimos qual a dimensão do bitmap
        //A utilização do Bounds.Width irá permitir que o programa "saiba" onde começa a aplicação
        Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(this.Bounds.Width, this.Bounds.Height);

        //Definimos o bitmap como imagem
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen);

        //O uso do this.Bounds é fundamental para que o printscreen apenas incida sobre a aplicação
        //O this.Bounds.Size determina automaticamente qual a dimensão da janela da aplicação
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(this.Bounds.X, this.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, this.Bounds.Size);

        //Por fim, basta apenas indicar o caminho, o nome da imagem, a extensão e o formato
        string caminho = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string nome = "PrintScreen Peopleware";
        printscreen.Save(caminho + "\\" + nome + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

Mas o código em questão só tirar print do própria janela.
Queria um que eu pudesse definir tipo: Google Chrome 
E independente da janela que estivesse aberta no meu pc, ele tiraria foto do Chrome. 
Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lembro de ter pego um código em algum lugar (provavelmente no próprio SO) para fazer isso (eu usava para printar a tela quando desse um erro, então enviar por email para a equipe de desenvolvimento).

Crie uma referência a um `RECT`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    private int _Left;
    private int _Top;
    private int _Right;
    private int _Bottom;

    public RECT(RECT Rectangle) : this(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom)
    {
    }
    public RECT(int Left, int Top, int Right, int Bottom)
    {
        _Left = Left;
        _Top = Top;
        _Right = Right;
        _Bottom = Bottom;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Y
    {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Left
    {
        get { return _Left; }
        set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Top
    {
        get { return _Top; }
        set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Right
    {
        get { return _Right; }
        set { _Right = value; }
    }
    public int Bottom
    {
        get { return _Bottom; }
        set { _Bottom = value; }
    }
    public int Height
    {
        get { return _Bottom - _Top; }
        set { _Bottom = value + _Top; }
    }
    public int Width
    {
        get { return _Right - _Left; }
        set { _Right = value + _Left; }
    }
    public Point Location
    {
        get { return new Point(Left, Top); }
        set
        {
            _Left = value.X;
            _Top = value.Y;
        }
    }
    public Size Size
    {
        get { return new Size(Width, Height); }
        set
        {
            _Right = value.Width + _Left;
            _Bottom = value.Height + _Top;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator Rectangle(RECT Rectangle)
    {
        return new Rectangle(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);
    }
    public static implicit operator RECT(Rectangle Rectangle)
    {
        return new RECT(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
        return Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
        return !Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "{Left: " + _Left + "; " + "Top: " + _Top + "; Right: " + _Right + "; Bottom: " + _Bottom + "}";
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(RECT Rectangle)
    {
        return Rectangle.Left == _Left && Rectangle.Top == _Top && Rectangle.Right == _Right && Rectangle.Bottom == _Bottom;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object Object)
    {
        if (Object is RECT)
        {
            return Equals((RECT)Object);
        }
        else if (Object is Rectangle)
        {
            return Equals(new RECT((Rectangle)Object));
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Depois adicione em alguma classe (ex: em um form) essas duas referências à métodos da **api win32**, e crie esse método `PrintarAplicativo()`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

    public static Bitmap PrintarAplicativo(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();

        PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);

        gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
        gfxBmp.Dispose();

        return bmp;
    }

}
```

Esse método recebe o `handle` do processo no qual você deseja tirar o print. Daí você usa ele assim, por exemplo:

```
private void btPrintScreenEcra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // tirando um print de algum "notepad" aberto...
    var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad")[0];
    using (var bmp = PrintarAplicativo(proc.MainWindowHandle))
    {
        SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "Imagens(*.png, *.jpeg) | *.png; *.jpeg | Todos Arquivos(*.*) | *.* ";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            bmp.Save(dialog.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

O primeiro método `Process.GetProcessesByName()` recebe o nome do processo. Se eu tivesse 3 notepads abertos, esse método retornaria um array contendo esses 3 processos. Estou aleatoriamente pegando o primeiro aberto (note que isso daria erro se não tivesse ao menos um notepad aberto).

Depois chamamos o método `PrintarAplicativo` passando o handle da tela principal daquele processo. Um aplicativo pode ter diversas *windows* dentro dele, e cada window tem sua própria Handle (lembro disso por ter trabalhado bastante com Delphi, e lá usávamos esse conceito para disparar **mensagens** com o PostMessage de uma tela para outra). Nesse caso, a main window representa a tela inteira do aplicativo, logo seria possível tirar o print de "subtelas" dentro daquele processo.

Esse método retorna o `Bitmap` pronto, então nesse exemplo eu abro uma caixa de diálogo para o usuário escolher onde salvar esse arquivo (mas você nem precisaria fazer isso, bastaria salvar diretamente em algum diretório sem o usuário nem ser incomodado).

---

Para o **chrome** em particular, é complicado pois pelo que sei o chrome cria uns 30 processos, note no meu caso:

[image: Gerenciador de Tarefas]

No entanto, eu fiz o teste abaixo, e de todos esses processos, somente um possui o handle da main window:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
// verificar se o processo tem interface gráfica
foreach (var proc in processes.Where(p => p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero))
{
    using (var bmp = PrintarAplicativo(proc.MainWindowHandle))
    {
        bmp.Save(string.Format("C:\\Users\\Alisson\\Pictures\\chrome-{0}.png", proc.Id));
    }
}
```

Que resultou na seguinte imagem:

[image: Chrome]

Comment: Caramba cara, VOCÊ ME AJUDOU MUUUUUITO, MUITO OBRIGADO!

Comment: @FredericoSampaio por nada!!! :D