# Manipular PrintScreen em C#

Tags: c#, fullscreen

A um tempo atrás um cara aqui do fórum me ajudou a montar um programa pra tirar foto de uma janela especifica que tivesse aberta no computador.
Queria ajuda pra saber se consigo nessa foto invés de ser da janela inteira, ser apenas uma parte da janela!

Link da pergunta:
[PrintScreen em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/207692/printscreen-em-c/207697?noredirect=1#comment424966_207697)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você irá precisar de 2 bibliotecas:

```
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

E para tirar a screenshot:

```
private void PrintScreen()
{  
    Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size); //Copia a imagem da tela
    printscreen.Save(@"C:\Temp\printscreen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg); //Salva a captura de tela
}
```

Documentações: [System.Drawing.Imaging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.110).aspx) e [System.Drawing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
Substituindo esses 0, consigo definir o lugar que eu quero que tire a foto ?

Comment: Sim, mas se você for mudar, recomendo usar pointers. Dê uma olha [nisso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Muito Obrigado cara, ajudou muuito!